# What is the difference in use between 迷失， 迷路， 走失 and 迷途？

Tags: meaning, difference

All of the words are defined as "to lose one's way".

Comment: (with the help of iciba:) lose one's way 迷路 seems to be most commonly used expression, and is a separable verb (迷了路）
迷途 less common，not separable，e。g。她走离了正路,迷途了.She strayed from the road and got lost.
迷失  lose (one's way, etc.), used with additional object e.g.迷失方向. 
走失   3.The child strayed away from home.
这孩子离家走失了

Answer (score 0, accepted):

迷路 is daily used expression,it means one get lost.e.g.我迷路了，I'm lost.
迷失，迷途 are written words,formal words,both of them mean lost,but 迷失 is a verb,迷途 is a noun.
走失 is a daily and formal word,basically it means one get lost,but the reason could be either one can't find the way or being abducted or kidnapped.